# How do I get the timeseries data plotting in matplotlib in certain timeframe(like 9 am-3pm)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have daily timeseries  data **from 9am to 3pm** but, when I am going plot these data in **matplotlib**, it is taking 24 hours as a day, but I want it take 9AM TO 3PM as a day . How do I get continuous daily graph for only 9 AM TO 3 PM?

[image]

This is what I got from my code.

Here is my sample data. I would like to have time-date v/s close plot without any data gap. Please help me.

Pardon me for any mistake here!

```py
    close   lot1    lot2    time-date
0   800.0   25  50  2020-09-15 11:01:00
1   900.0   25  50  2020-09-15 14:33:00
2   885.85  50  75  2020-09-16 11:45:00
3   791.4   50  125 2020-09-16 12:50:00
4   1082.45 50  75  2020-09-16 14:30:00
5   1060.1  25  125 2020-09-16 14:35:00
6   855.1   50  100 2020-09-17 11:36:00
7   830.0   250 125 2020-09-17 11:39:00
8   815.0   25  125 2020-09-17 11:40:00
9   804.8   25  400 2020-09-17 11:41:00
10  803.0   275 400 2020-09-17 11:44:00
11  791.0   150 650 2020-09-17 11:54:00
12  791.0   100 650 2020-09-17 11:55:00
13  780.65  25  900 2020-09-17 11:59:00
14  784.8   25  925 2020-09-17 12:01:00
15  825.0   25  925 2020-09-17 12:16:00
16  812.3   25  925 2020-09-17 13:25:00
17  816.7   25  950 2020-09-17 14:23:00
18  811.0   25  950 2020-09-17 14:48:00
19  764.5   25  975 2020-09-17 15:11:00
20  808.95  100 1000    2020-09-17 15:20:00
21  805.85  50  1100    2020-09-17 15:24:00
22  798.85  25  1125    2020-09-17 15:27:00
23  812.45  25  1150    2020-09-18 09:17:00
24  814.9   50  1225    2020-09-18 09:18:00
25  840.95  25  1225    2020-09-18 09:19:00
26  839.0   25  1225    2020-09-18 09:20:00
27  827.1   25  1175    2020-09-18 09:23:00
28  812.0   100 1150    2020-09-18 09:28:00
29  770.0   100 1200    2020-09-18 09:32:00
30  784.95  25  1200    2020-09-18 09:33:00
31  790.0   25  1325    2020-09-18 09:35:00
32  788.7   25  1325    2020-09-18 09:37:00
33  789.25  75  1375    2020-09-18 09:38:00
34  810.95  25  1375    2020-09-18 09:42:00
35  827.3   25  1375    2020-09-18 09:43:00
36  821.25  25  1400    2020-09-18 09:45:00
37  809.45  25  1375    2020-09-18 09:57:00
38  820.6   50  1400    2020-09-18 10:01:00
39  835.15  50  1425    2020-09-18 10:04:00
40  832.9   100 1425    2020-09-18 10:05:00
41  839.5   25  1425    2020-09-18 10:07:00
42  831.85  25  1475    2020-09-18 10:09:00
43  808.0   50  1400    2020-09-18 10:14:00
44  795.0   25  1400    2020-09-18 10:17:00
45  780.0   50  1350    2020-09-18 10:26:00
46  802.7   100 1350    2020-09-18 10:28:00
47  792.5   50  1425    2020-09-18 10:29:00
48  790.7   75  1425    2020-09-18 10:30:00
49  793.0   25  1425    2020-09-18 10:34:00
50  789.65  25  1425    2020-09-18 10:35:00
51  796.9   50  1425    2020-09-18 10:37:00
52  791.5   25  1425    2020-09-18 10:38:00
53  797.1   50  1475    2020-09-18 10:39:00
54  760.0   50  1475    2020-09-18 10:41:00
55  780.65  100 1475    2020-09-18 10:42:00
56  782.4   50  1475    2020-09-18 10:43:00
57  780.0   100 1550    2020-09-18 10:45:00
58  788.6   75  1650    2020-09-18 10:50:00
59  794.75  25  1650    2020-09-18 10:53:00
60  792.8   150 1650    2020-09-18 10:54:00
61  806.5   150 1650    2020-09-18 10:55:00
62  801.0   50  1775    2020-09-18 10:57:00
63  789.4   50  1775    2020-09-18 10:58:00
64  804.55  25  1775    2020-09-18 11:00:00
65  792.0   25  1775    2020-09-18 11:03:00
66  793.9   50  1775    2020-09-18 11:05:00
67  785.1   225 1850    2020-09-18 11:06:00
68  782.45  50  1850    2020-09-18 11:07:00
69  778.05  50  1850    2020-09-18 11:08:00
70  766.2   175 2000    2020-09-18 11:12:00
71  772.1   75  2000    2020-09-18 11:13:00
72  758.9   100 2200    2020-09-18 11:14:00
73  771.0   250 2200    2020-09-18 11:15:00
74  764.7   25  2200    2020-09-18 11:16:00
75  777.45  125 2450    2020-09-18 11:19:00
76  778.2   25  2550    2020-09-18 11:22:00
77  777.85  25  2550    2020-09-18 11:23:00
78  783.85  125 2600    2020-09-18 11:24:00
79  776.8   100 2700    2020-09-18 11:26:00
80  776.2   75  2700    2020-09-18 11:28:00
81  785.8   75  2875    2020-09-18 11:30:00
82  787.45  100 2875    2020-09-18 11:31:00
83  789.9   25  2875    2020-09-18 11:32:00
84  798.1   75  2875    2020-09-18 11:33:00
85  792.85  50  2925    2020-09-18 11:38:00
86  794.2   100 2925    2020-09-18 11:40:00
87  796.55  25  3050    2020-09-18 11:42:00
88  800.0   25  3050    2020-09-18 11:44:00
89  781.9   525 3050    2020-09-18 11:50:00
90  787.85  50  3525    2020-09-18 11:51:00
91  787.15  350 3525    2020-09-18 11:53:00
92  789.0   25  3525    2020-09-18 11:54:00
93  801.9   50  3375    2020-09-18 11:57:00
94  793.3   25  3400    2020-09-18 12:02:00
95  793.4   25  3000    2020-09-18 12:07:00
96  795.0   25  3000    2020-09-18 12:08:00
97  800.95  25  3025    2020-09-18 12:09:00
98  800.9   75  3025    2020-09-18 12:10:00
99  792.85  25  3025    2020-09-18 12:11:00
100 785.3   75  3075    2020-09-18 12:12:00
101 790.8   50  3075    2020-09-18 12:13:00
102 782.0   125 3075    2020-09-18 12:14:00
103 791.9   25  3125    2020-09-18 12:15:00
104 789.9   25  3125    2020-09-18 12:16:00
105 799.65  125 3150    2020-09-18 12:18:00
106 795.15  50  3025    2020-09-18 12:30:00
107 794.05  25  3075    2020-09-18 12:36:00
108 785.75  25  3075    2020-09-18 12:37:00
109 758.5   25  3100    2020-09-18 12:45:00
110 775.0   50  3100    2020-09-18 12:46:00
111 771.6   100 3100    2020-09-18 12:47:00
112 768.6   25  3125    2020-09-18 12:48:00
113 786.95  50  3150    2020-09-18 12:53:00
114 781.5   25  3150    2020-09-18 12:54:00
115 774.95  25  3100    2020-09-18 12:58:00
116 771.7   25  3100    2020-09-18 12:59:00
117 766.7   50  3150    2020-09-18 13:00:00
118 764.55  125 3150    2020-09-18 13:01:00
119 767.0   200 3150    2020-09-18 13:02:00
120 770.0   250 3175    2020-09-18 13:05:00
121 770.15  75  3075    2020-09-18 13:06:00
122 789.15  50  3075    2020-09-18 13:08:00
123 777.7   50  3125    2020-09-18 13:10:00
124 787.0   50  3125    2020-09-18 13:11:00
125 790.0   100 3000    2020-09-18 13:14:00
126 795.0   275 3000    2020-09-18 13:15:00
127 775.0   25  3000    2020-09-18 13:20:00
128 780.0   75  2900    2020-09-18 13:21:00
129 774.15  75  2900    2020-09-18 13:22:00
130 769.0   100 2825    2020-09-18 13:24:00
131 753.2   175 2825    2020-09-18 13:25:00
132 761.7   25  2825    2020-09-18 13:26:00
133 775.0   75  2975    2020-09-18 13:30:00
134 766.15  650 3000    2020-09-18 13:37:00
135 767.5   25  3375    2020-09-18 13:40:00
136 778.0   25  3375    2020-09-18 13:42:00
137 782.0   25  3375    2020-09-18 13:43:00
138 776.5   25  3375    2020-09-18 13:44:00
139 796.1   75  3375    2020-09-18 13:45:00
140 795.2   25  3175    2020-09-18 13:48:00
141 802.55  175 3175    2020-09-18 13:49:00
142 806.3   100 3175    2020-09-18 13:50:00
143 806.65  125 3450    2020-09-18 13:51:00
144 788.2   50  3450    2020-09-18 13:52:00
145 796.25  50  3600    2020-09-18 13:55:00
146 795.0   25  3600    2020-09-18 13:56:00
147 784.4   25  3250    2020-09-18 14:01:00
148 790.0   25  3175    2020-09-18 14:05:00
149 790.0   25  3200    2020-09-18 14:06:00
150 780.0   25  3200    2020-09-18 14:07:00
151 775.0   225 3200    2020-09-18 14:08:00
152 779.0   100 3450    2020-09-18 14:10:00
153 767.0   100 3500    2020-09-18 14:12:00
154 769.0   25  3500    2020-09-18 14:13:00
155 759.7   25  3625    2020-09-18 14:17:00
156 764.45  100 3650    2020-09-18 14:18:00
157 750.0   25  3650    2020-09-18 14:19:00
158 701.9   525 3650    2020-09-18 14:20:00
159 631.0   1725    4050    2020-09-18 14:21:00
160 600.0   275 4050    2020-09-18 14:22:00
161 643.5   500 4050    2020-09-18 14:23:00
162 606.9   475 4275    2020-09-18 14:24:00
163 599.0   1000    4275    2020-09-18 14:25:00
164 590.45  675 4275    2020-09-18 14:26:00
165 605.0   925 4950    2020-09-18 14:27:00
166 614.3   600 4950    2020-09-18 14:28:00
167 600.05  775 4950    2020-09-18 14:29:00
168 595.35  1150    7025    2020-09-18 14:30:00
169 596.2   525 7025    2020-09-18 14:31:00
170 596.8   975 7025    2020-09-18 14:32:00
171 584.0   200 8125    2020-09-18 14:33:00
172 550.0   1750    8125    2020-09-18 14:34:00
173 552.2   1825    8125    2020-09-18 14:35:00
174 554.65  600 8750    2020-09-18 14:36:00
175 565.4   925 8750    2020-09-18 14:37:00
176 565.0   150 8750    2020-09-18 14:38:00
177 583.95  450 9150    2020-09-18 14:39:00
178 561.4   975 9150    2020-09-18 14:40:00
179 566.8   3450    9150    2020-09-18 14:41:00
180 563.35  425 10525   2020-09-18 14:42:00
181 565.4   700 10525   2020-09-18 14:43:00
182 570.0   650 10525   2020-09-18 14:44:00
183 572.8   200 11125   2020-09-18 14:45:00
184 595.25  750 11125   2020-09-18 14:46:00
185 585.75  625 11125   2020-09-18 14:47:00
186 593.4   475 10925   2020-09-18 14:48:00
187 590.0   950 10925   2020-09-18 14:49:00
188 576.4   775 10925   2020-09-18 14:50:00
189 596.55  775 10800   2020-09-18 14:51:00
190 595.95  475 10800   2020-09-18 14:52:00
191 593.95  725 10800   2020-09-18 14:53:00
192 611.45  1500    10550   2020-09-18 14:54:00
193 618.0   1050    10550   2020-09-18 14:55:00
194 600.0   1150    10550   2020-09-18 14:56:00
195 609.15  575 11025   2020-09-18 14:57:00
196 615.6   375 11025   2020-09-18 14:58:00
197 604.4   875 11025   2020-09-18 14:59:00
198 591.3   1225    11375   2020-09-18 15:00:00
199 600.0   1100    11375   2020-09-18 15:01:00
200 597.8   1800    11375   2020-09-18 15:02:00
201 605.0   550 12625   2020-09-18 15:03:00
202 599.1   325 12625   2020-09-18 15:04:00
203 606.2   500 12625   2020-09-18 15:05:00
204 614.65  850 12625   2020-09-18 15:06:00
205 616.0   1225    12625   2020-09-18 15:07:00
206 622.5   1325    12625   2020-09-18 15:08:00
207 620.0   750 13850   2020-09-18 15:09:00
208 632.0   525 13850   2020-09-18 15:10:00
209 630.3   375 13850   2020-09-18 15:11:00
210 635.0   425 13575   2020-09-18 15:12:00
211 630.85  400 13575   2020-09-18 15:13:00
212 627.45  275 13575   2020-09-18 15:14:00
213 620.7   200 13700   2020-09-18 15:15:00
214 622.4   200 13700   2020-09-18 15:16:00
215 631.6   625 13700   2020-09-18 15:17:00
216 624.95  525 13100   2020-09-18 15:18:00
217 632.25  775 13100   2020-09-18 15:19:00
218 610.7   350 13100   2020-09-18 15:20:00
219 602.0   575 13175   2020-09-18 15:21:00
220 612.4   200 13175   2020-09-18 15:22:00
221 617.25  325 13175   2020-09-18 15:23:00
222 617.8   300 13650   2020-09-18 15:24:00
223 622.1   600 13650   2020-09-18 15:25:00
224 622.2   250 13650   2020-09-18 15:26:00
225 623.7   300 13425   2020-09-18 15:27:00
226 622.5   425 13425   2020-09-18 15:28:00
227 621.0   375 13425   2020-09-18 15:29:00
228 567.55  1075    13275   2020-09-21 09:15:00
229 565.0   2100    13275   2020-09-21 09:16:00
230 560.0   1100    14925   2020-09-21 09:17:00
231 562.15  625 14925   2020-09-21 09:18:00
232 556.45  850 14925   2020-09-21 09:19:00
233 543.1   1525    16450   2020-09-21 09:20:00
234 538.0   800 16450   2020-09-21 09:21:00
235 537.45  575 16450   2020-09-21 09:22:00
236 544.4   775 16825   2020-09-21 09:23:00
237 545.7   500 16825   2020-09-21 09:24:00
238 551.4   550 16825   2020-09-21 09:25:00
239 544.25  900 17625   2020-09-21 09:26:00
240 538.0   1850    17625   2020-09-21 09:27:00
241 534.85  525 17625   2020-09-21 09:28:00
242 534.5   425 18775   2020-09-21 09:29:00
243 547.1   1075    18775   2020-09-21 09:30:00
244 536.85  375 18775   2020-09-21 09:31:00
245 547.6   375 19775   2020-09-21 09:32:00
246 540.25  350 19775   2020-09-21 09:33:00
247 541.2   375 19775   2020-09-21 09:34:00
248 544.6   175 18650   2020-09-21 09:35:00
249 542.55  250 18650   2020-09-21 09:36:00
250 539.65  550 18650   2020-09-21 09:37:00
251 531.15  2150    19175   2020-09-21 09:38:00
252 530.1   825 19175   2020-09-21 09:39:00
253 518.7   1575    19175   2020-09-21 09:40:00
254 520.95  575 20475   2020-09-21 09:41:00
255 511.45  1250    20475   2020-09-21 09:42:00
256 517.45  1025    20475   2020-09-21 09:43:00
257 515.0   550 21150   2020-09-21 09:44:00
258 515.0   1125    21150   2020-09-21 09:45:00
259 518.9   425 21150   2020-09-21 09:46:00
260 514.95  550 21500   2020-09-21 09:47:00
261 509.8   1625    21500   2020-09-21 09:48:00
262 507.55  475 21500   2020-09-21 09:49:00
263 514.35  500 21975   2020-09-21 09:50:00
264 524.5   500 21975   2020-09-21 09:51:00
265 527.45  550 21975   2020-09-21 09:52:00
266 527.3   675 21550   2020-09-21 09:53:00
267 521.3   525 21550   2020-09-21 09:54:00
268 520.0   275 21550   2020-09-21 09:55:00
269 519.5   750 21600   2020-09-21 09:56:00
270 516.7   400 21600   2020-09-21 09:57:00
271 517.75  350 21600   2020-09-21 09:58:00
272 511.9   575 21850   2020-09-21 09:59:00
273 507.9   1175    21850   2020-09-21 10:00:00
274 510.05  525 21850   2020-09-21 10:01:00
275 515.85  1025    22350   2020-09-21 10:02:00
276 514.25  600 22350   2020-09-21 10:03:00
277 520.05  650 22350   2020-09-21 10:04:00
278 518.9   950 22850   2020-09-21 10:05:00
279 512.25  550 22850   2020-09-21 10:06:00
280 513.65  650 22850   2020-09-21 10:07:00
281 514.0   525 24300   2020-09-21 10:08:00
282 506.3   875 24300   2020-09-21 10:09:00
283 490.85  1825    24300   2020-09-21 10:10:00
284 499.0   300 25050   2020-09-21 10:11:00
285 495.0   975 25050   2020-09-21 10:12:00
286 497.15  1125    25050   2020-09-21 10:13:00
287 496.8   625 24875   2020-09-21 10:14:00
288 492.95  1075    24875   2020-09-21 10:15:00
289 497.6   1125    24875   2020-09-21 10:16:00
290 502.3   775 24450   2020-09-21 10:17:00
291 501.85  475 24450   2020-09-21 10:18:00
292 502.85  800 24450   2020-09-21 10:19:00
293 511.35  825 24700   2020-09-21 10:20:00
294 537.0   1850    24700   2020-09-21 10:21:00
295 531.55  2025    24700   2020-09-21 10:22:00
296 558.45  2825    24675   2020-09-21 10:23:00
297 555.25  625 24675   2020-09-21 10:24:00
298 577.0   4275    24675   2020-09-21 10:25:00
299 574.0   1075    23500   2020-09-21 10:26:00
300 569.4   600 23500   2020-09-21 10:27:00
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please create a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including some generated representative dummy data and your code

Comment: your graph looks continuous to me.  You should clarify.

Comment: It counts whole day time-period , but I want  plot between 9 AM TO 3 PM

Comment: Hi, you should create an axes instance and plot each day individually on this axes with a loop.

Comment: Sir, I got your thought but I'm kinda beginner, could you please explain with example? I'm trying to figure out this from last two days.